# DLOOKUP for filling a text box using 2 combo box selections

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

```
=DLookUp([GTIN],"tblGTIN","VarietyCode = " & [Forms]![frmCaseLabel]![VarietySelected] & "AND PackType =" & [Forms]![frmCaseLabel]![PackInput])
```

Returns: #Error

```
=DLookUp([GTIN],"tblGTIN","VarietyCode = " & [Forms]![frmCaseLabel]![VarietySelected].[Text] & "" & "AND PackType =" & [Forms]![frmCaseLabel]![PackInput].[Text] & "")
```

Returns: #Type!

I am having issues populating a text box, using above DLookUP however I can't find what's wrong. GTIN is a number, varietyselected is a string, packinput is string.

I am sure the same can be achieved with SELECT, which I am willing to use but I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you are doing wrong here:

- If fields are text, then they need to be wrapped in single quotes.
- You need to have a space before the `AND`, otherwise this gets joined into the value that you are looking up;
- The `.Text` property of a control is only available when the control has the focus, and allows you to grab the uncommitted value. Normally you should use the default property, which is `.Value` (and can be omitted).

Putting this all together, it should look like:

```
=DLookup("GTIN","tblGTIN","VarietyCode='" & Forms!frmCaseLabel!VarietySelected & "' AND PackType='" & Forms!frmCaseLabel!PackInput & "'")
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This worked! Ironic this is for labeling apples!